# SQL Server - Insert into table, values from another table

Tags: sql-server, insert

Firstly, I have read through other posts on this page regarding similar issues but I cannot figure out where I am going wrong. I want to populate a column of [table1] with values from another column in [table2].

When I run,

```
insert into Staged.dbo.factSales(Date)
    select SaleDate 
    from Staged.dbo.SaleDates
```

I get the following error

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'SaleValue', table 'Staged.dbo.factSales'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

`SaleValue` is the column in `Staged.dbo.factSales` and design-wise, comes after 'Date' - SaleID, OrderID, ProductID, BranchID, EmployeeID, Date, SaleValue.

Does anyone have any idea where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Marcin

Comment: Use brackets to enclose your ANOTHER sql statement

Comment: The answer is the error message

Comment: Someone thought it wise to put a not null restriction on the factSales table for the column SaleValue.  Change your insert to provide the appropriate saleVale!  Askyourself why would that restriction be there, and why are you trying to insert a record without one.  Are you doing something wrong by omiting the value or is the restriction no longer valid?  Both of these are business questions that only you can really answer.

Answer (score 1):

SalesValue does not allow nulls, so supply a zero.

```
Insert into Staged.dbo.factSales (Date,SaleValue)
Select SaleDate,0 from Staged.dbo.SaleDates
```

Comment: Or supply `'0'` if is a string, You also can change your table to allow nulls for that field.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Correct.  I made an assumption.

Comment: Why do I have to include SaleValue if I want to only want to affect a specific column? Also, SaleValue already contains valuable data so I cant just override it with a meaningless 0

Comment: @MPol because your fact table does not accept nulls in SalesValue.  Without it, you are trying to add records which would have a null value in SalesValue.

Comment: Okay, so my sql command replaces all data, not just insert it?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using

```
update Staged.dbo.factSales set Staged.dbo.factSales.Date = Staged.dbo.SaleDates.SaleDate from Staged.dbo.factSales inner join Staged.dbo.SaleDates on Staged.dbo.factSales.SaleID = Staged.dbo.SaleDates.SaleID
```